# Error in fetch request doesn't stop function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch

i've implemented firebase login on my website,
i send the information to my server. there i create the session and csrf token.

but i see that if my csrf doesn't match, i get the error, but the function continues to run as if it's a successful login.

here is the code:

```
postIdTokenToSessionLogin("/sessionLogin", idToken, csrfToken).then(
      function() {
        // Redirect to profile on success.
        console.log("login succesful"); //this gets logged even if "postIdTokenToSessionLogin" gets caught 

        // window.location.assign("/profile");
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error); //i need this to run

        window.location.assign("/");
      }
    );


postIdTokenToSessionLogin = async function(url, idToken, csrfToken) {
  // POST to session login endpoint.
  const data = {
    idToken,
    _csrf: csrfToken
  };
  console.log(data);

  options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  // POST to session login endpoint.
  return fetch(url, options).catch(err => {
     throw err; //---------here i do get the error, 
  });
};
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: You'll have to show the code that calls `postIdTokenToSessionLogin()`.  That's likely where the problem is.  I think you tried to show part of it, but we need to see the whole bit where you call that function and attempt to handle the error.  Also, I hope you realize that `fetch()` does not reject when there's a 4xx or 5xx error.  It only rejects if the actual network request failed (host not found, DNS not found, network down, connection interrupted, etc...).

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, looks like i missed a bit of the code, so how can i do that the .then() goes to the error callback?

Comment: So, what you're' implying in your question won't happen.  If you `throw err` inside the `fetch().catch()` and the code actually gets into that catch and gets thrown, then it will go to the error handler in the calling code you show.  So, my guess is that you aren't actually getting into the `.catch()` because `fetch()` is resolving just fine and perhaps returning a 4xx or 5xx error.  You can check `response.ok` from fetch in your `.then()` handler.

Comment: So, apparently my comment was exactly right.  You weren't actually getting into the `.catch()` at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes. Lol. Thank you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rely on the `ok` property of the `Response`:

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/status/500')
.then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
        return res;
    } else {
        throw res;
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error: ', err.status);
});
```